# LUKS Encrypted USB on macOS

Tags: linux, macos, usb

How can I mount the LUKS usb I created on Manjaro Linux to macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of yet there is no way you can mount LUKS-encrypted volumes on macOS. Although you definitely have the alternative of installing a linux VM on your system, but it is very Time and resource consuming.

Comment: Now there is. See https://superuser.com/a/1807049/1157555

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Linsk](https://github.com/AlexSSD7/linsk). It is a utility that wraps around a lightweight Alpine Linux VM, allowing you to mount any Linux file system (including **LUKS**) that is then exposed to the host machine through a network file share.

**Disclosure**: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

If using VirtualBox note that you typically need to launch via sudo so that VB can mount the USB. This isn’t particularly obvious..but if you already have virtualbox it isn’t particularly hard or time consuming

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).